# Is it possible to delete a single execution plan from cache on Azure SQL DB?

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, sql-execution-plan, dbcc

**Conclusion**

You can not. Microsoft explicitly states: "you cannot manually remove an execution plan from the cache" [in this article called 'Understanding the Procedure Cache on SQL Azure'](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/understanding-the-procedure-cache-on-sql-azure/).

**Original Question**

On SQL Server a single execution plan can be deleted from the cache using `[DBCC FREEPROCCACHE(plan_handle varbinary(64))][1]`. There is different `[documentation about DBCC FREEPROCCACHE on SQL Azure][2]`. It seems that it removes all cached execution plans from all compute nodes and or control nodes (whatever those nodes might be, I don't know). I do not understand why `SQL` on Azure of the Server version would differ in this aspect.

However, I am looking for a way to delete a single execution plan from the cache on `Azure`. Is there any way to delete a single execution plan on `Azure`? Maybe using a query instead of a `DBCC`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to remove single execution plan from cache.

If your execution plan is related to only few tables/one table and  if you are ok with removal of cache for those tables as well, then you can alter the table ,add a non null column and remove the column.This will force flush the cache ..

Changing schema of the tables causes cache flush(not single plan, all plans) for those tables involved

> I do not understand why SQL on Azure of the Server version would differ in this aspect.

This has to do with database as a offering, you are offered a database(this may be in some server with multiple databases) and some dbcc commands affect whole instance,so they kind of banned all DBCC commands.There is a new offering called [Managed instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance)(which is same as on premises server,but with high availabilty of Azure database), you may want to check that as well

Comment: Great to see a link to point to information describing why this is not possible on Azure. Also great to have a kind-of-a-hack alternative to mark the execution plan as outdated, or flushing the cache as you put it.

Comment: We are also in process of migrating to managed instance, if you have only one db,then azure db fits well,other than that managed instance may be better